# I found this script that go through the current database only and identifiy unused index but I wanna to go through all the databases

Tags: sql-server, loops

I found this script that give you unused index however it runs only per databases how make it run through all the databases on server

```
   SELECT  o.name ,
        indexname = i.name ,
        i.index_id ,
        reads = user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups ,
        writes = user_updates ,
        rows = ( SELECT SUM(p.rows)
                 FROM   sys.partitions p
                 WHERE  p.index_id = s.index_id
                        AND s.object_id = p.object_id
               ) ,
        CASE WHEN s.user_updates < 1 THEN 100
             ELSE 1.00 * ( s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups )
                  / s.user_updates
        END AS reads_per_write ,
        'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '.'
        + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)) AS 'drop statement'
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = s.index_id
                                    AND s.object_id = i.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas c ON o.schema_id = c.schema_id
WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(s.object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
        AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
        AND i.type_desc = 'nonclustered'
        AND i.is_primary_key = 0
        AND i.is_unique_constraint = 0
        AND ( SELECT    SUM(p.rows)
              FROM      sys.partitions p
              WHERE     p.index_id = s.index_id
                        AND s.object_id = p.object_id
            ) > 10000
ORDER BY reads_per_write ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a line in your code that is restricting the records to the current database:

```
AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
```

in your where clause. if you remove that, it will give you stats on all of the databases and objects you have access to.

you may want to also include the database name if you remove that line:

```
SELECT 
    db_name(database_id) DATABASE_NAME,
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance My plan is to create  the job in master database where I can run through all the database

Comment: I remover AND s.database_id = DB_ID() as you suggested but still the same result

Comment: do you have access to the other databases? or does the credentials you're using?

Comment: Yes I do have permission

Comment: To make it clear I just want to create a job that go through all of the databases and give the result  from master database

Comment: That's odd, I tried it out and got results from multiple databases. I'm not sure what is causing the issue. You should be able to run the script from a SQL Agent job, and it'll run under the owner's credentials

Comment: I Got this massage Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LUNIFIED". A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7395)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LUNIFIED" returned message "Cannot start more transactions on this session.". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

Comment: it looks like it's complaining because multiple transactions are trying to run against a linked server. You could try moving the processing to that server, or look into the [XACT_ABORT option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) to see if that's appropriate for you

Comment: Yes I fixed that and I tried but it only gave one database

Comment: You could try taking out the last line in that where statement. it might be filtering out more than you wanted

Comment: this portion: 
AND ( SELECT    SUM(p.rows)
              FROM      sys.partitions p
              WHERE     p.index_id = s.index_id
                        AND s.object_id = p.object_id
            ) > 10000

Comment: sorry to hear that, it seems like it might be either a permission issue or something else like no nonclustered indexes in the other databases. The SQL isn't really filtering anything out at this point except primary keys and unique constraints, so that leaves what the dm view is filtering out, or the actual indexes.

Comment: Thank so much for your help though